# How to compile and run C code?

Tags: c

I have purchased ***The C Programming Language ANSI C Version*** book for learning C. In that, there is no instruction for setting up the environment for developing the C programs.

Please help me how to compile and run the code explained in the book.

**EDIT : I have Windows 7 installed as the OS"**

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows/Linux or other? ... Google is also good source of information...

Comment: LOL Why dont you google it and find some better IDE's ? and what IDE Does the Book suggest you to work on ? You didnt even mention the COmpiler and ask us to help you. Hows that possible :(  we are helpless . Atleast let we know the compiler Name so that we can help you to make it out.

Comment: @niko :Buddy, there is nothing mentioned in the book that's why asked here. One of the best thing about moderators here is that they are waiting to close the question as soon as it arrives. Bingo, if you dont know the answer, then don't close it merely saying its vague and cannot be answered. There are four answers below and all are real.

Comment: @PanKaj Upadhyay The reason to close your question becuase its not a question but a discussion its like your asking which compiler to choose , Sorry about since they have closed the question. Well As I have seen your profile you sound like you worked more on visual c# right. Then it must be easy for you to work on visual c++ though for a begginer its not a good one ! As far I think . In visual c++ You can work both c and c++ .

Comment: as a begginner I suggest you to work on Turbo c borlando. ofcourse it doesnot support multithreading but it makes you analyze whats going under the hood with good picture. You can also choose cygwin(supports multithreading) but Its Little bit tuff to install on windows platform :P and also may be ,a eclipse or gcc or dev c++ 4.6 or vc++ (all those are famous c compilers). Mostly people you gcc compiler though I never worked on .but as a begginer Turbo c is the best suitable to work on . and its upto you to choose and its very easy to install just extract and run tcc.exe thats it.

Comment: @niko : Thanks mate. I will definitely look into Turbo C. As far as VS 2010 goes, i am unable to proceed. Since the book i am using is from the 90's something. Infact, i am unable to code a hello program in VS :P

Comment: Yeah vs 2010 its bit scary at the beginning lol

Comment: http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/6619/Download.aspx http://kingofkings007.blogspot.com/2009/10/free-download-turbo-c-v201-by-borland.html I belive turboc 2.01 by borland is still holding strong positiong. Above are the 2 links to download I dont know whether they are working or no becuase Im @ my office and i cannot open them oopz and dont forget to work on gcc and vc++ after some time working on them is much better as turbo c is just a learning compiler its a start for the beginners to be a expert you have to move to gcc and vc++ . Thanks need to go for lunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). I've chosen [Code:Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)  a long time ago and I am still happy with it. Alternatively you can use NetBeans, Eclipse, DevCpp, ... There are a lot of IDEs for C or C++ available.

Comment: I prefer (g)vim and GCC myself. Using IDEs for C seems like a bit much.

Answer (score 1):

If on Mac/Linux, you can simply use `make myprogram` (in a terminal) to easily compile a single-file C program where the source file is called myprogram.c

For more complex programs with several source files, system dependencies et c, it quickly gets much more complex. Use google to find the basics of GCC, the default compiler on UNIX systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, you could either use the Visual Studio from Microsoft (excellent, but not free) or [Eclipse with CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).

This provides you a full IDE with nice debugging support.

However, if you don't want to use an IDE but learn to build programs from scratch, [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) would be an option including GCC and Make.